# Can't retrieve with PHP post variables serialized with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, post

Upon submitting a form via Ajax with jQuery and serializing it, I have trouble retrieving the post variables with PHP. Here's my code:

JS (main.js)

```
$.ajax({
  url: WPaAjax.ajaxurl,
  type: 'post',      
  data: {
    action: 'send_message',
    data: $(this).serialize()
  },
  success: function(response) {
    $('.contact_form').html(response);
  }
});
```

PHP (functions.php)

```
function load_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');  
  wp_enqueue_script('main_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/scripts/main.js', array('jquery'), true);
  wp_localize_script('main_js', 'WPaAjax', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');

function send_message_function() { 
  echo $_POST['form_last_name'];
  echo '<br><br>';
  echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST) . '</pre>';
  exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_send_message', 'send_message_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_message', 'send_message_function');
```

When submitting the form, the individual post variables (for example `$_POST['form_last_name']`) are empty.

If I print_r the $_POST variable I get this though:

```
Array ( [action] => send_message [data] => form_last_name=Johnson&form_first_name=David&form_email=djohnson%40hotmail.com&form_subject=&form_telephone=01110259923&form_code_postal=C11+3HR&form_message=test [some_variable] => some_value )
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to retrieve values from the structure you paste:

```
Array ( 
  [action] => send_message 
  [data] => form_last_name=Johnson&form_first_name=David&form_email=djohnson%40hotmail.com&form_subject=&form_telephone=01110259923&form_code_postal=C11+3HR&form_message=test 
  [some_variable] => some_value 
)
```

Do it as follows:

```
parse_str($_POST['data'], $temp)

// Now you can access those vars on $temp
echo $temp['form_last_name'];
echo $temp['form_first_name'];
```

See you are trying to access a field `$_POST['form_last_name']` which in fact, is inside a query string on your post `$_POST['data']` field.

Have a look at the php method [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and carefully review the `$_POST` data you receive.

Comment: Thanks it does work, but is it the right way to do this whole thing? It seems a little hacky to me, what do you think?

Comment: what is hacky, under your point of view? I just show you how to decode the post field that has a query string on it, as I saw `$_POST['form_last_name']`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would solve it:

```
var data = { action: 'send_message' },
$form = $(this);
$.each( $form.serializeArray(), function () {
    data[ this.name ] = this.value;
} );

$.ajax( {
    ...
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    ...
} )
```

Then you can access the variables via php as `$_POST['action']` and `$_POST['form_last_name']`

Comment: Thanks, but using your code I get a '400 (Bad Request)' error